# Angular 2 @Input parameter from selected dropdown

Tags: angular, input

I am having issue with passing `@input` parameter from parent component. I am trying to create a cascading dropdowns. I have one dropdown in parent component and one in child. On selecting parent drop-down, I want to populate child dropdown. I am trying to achieve it using `@Input` parameter, but it doesn't seem working.

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/uyE5XIasBdh3OwQhvHwb?p=preview]

export class Hero {
  constructor(public id:number, public name:string)  
}

App Component 

import { Hero } from './hero';

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
     <select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let hero of heroes" value="{{hero.id}}">{{hero.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: string): void {
    this.selectedHero = new Hero(hero,hero);
  }
}


Child Component

@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  template:`
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <div>details!</div>
      <h2>Name: {{hero.name}}</h2>
      <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>

    </div>`
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  @Input()
  hero: Hero;
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question. There is a reason why SO doesn't allow Plunker links without also adding code directly.

Comment: I couldn't see dropdown in child component in the above plunker code. The only input you're passing from parent to child is "hero" , which is a <input>

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my first ever post therefore i didn't know. @GopinathShiva the drop down is in app.components.ts template.

Comment: That's not helpful. Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable, thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[ngValue]` to use objects as values for `<option>`. This way `[(ngModel)]="selectedHero"` assigns such an object to `selectedHero`

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hrcCVSSIWNG6Lo2CghQE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks alot. i have been pulling my hair since 3 days.